# Swift: if a do return try fails does catch execute

Tags: swift, return

I am working on a piece of code that is going to fetch an array of `NSManagedObject`s from CoreData. When using a do catch statement in my code it doesn't seem right to do it this way, but it is the simplest way I can write this line of code.

In any other scenario when you use the `return` statement you are jumping out of the current function you are in. And you can be assured that no other code in your function will execute past the `return` statement. I am wondering if the same applies to Swift's `do catch` paradigm.

```
class func getAll() -> [MMNotification] {
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<MMNotification>(entityName: "MMNotification")
    do {
        return try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    }
    catch {
        // Will this 'catch' if the try fails, 
        // even if we said we are 'return'ing right before the 'try'?
        return []
    }
}
```

Here I am fetching a list of notifications stored in CoreData. In the `do` block you can see the line of code in question.

**QUESTION**

Will the `catch` block execute if the `try` fails after already stating that the function should `return`?

Comment: A simple test case using `do/catch` and a failed `return try` would have given you your answer.

Comment: Well if the call to `context.fetch` does throw an error, then it won't return a value – so what would you expect `getAll()` to return in that case, without an alternative return value being specified in the `catch`?

Comment: If you're indifferent as to what the thrown error actually is (which you seem to be, given your sample code), then you can just do this: `return try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) ?? []`

Comment: @rmaddy It's not simple if Swift won't compile because of errors OP may not know how to fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have should work as expected. Basically what happens is if a throw occurs at *any* time within a do, the catch is called and any code after the throw will not be executed.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, the `catch` block will execute if the `try` in `return try` fails. The return will not happen.

Here's a little code to prove it to yourself. Paste it into a new playground to try it out.

```
import UIKit

let shouldFail = true

enum DemoError:Error {
    case shouldFail
}

func failableGetter() throws -> String {
    if shouldFail { throw DemoError.shouldFail }
    return "Succeeded"
}

func fetchInfo() -> String {
    do {
        return try failableGetter()
    } catch {
        return "Failed"
    }
}

print(fetchInfo()) // "Failed" or "Succeeded" depending on shouldFail
```

When `shouldFail` is `true`, the `failableGetter()` throws an error and the `do-catch` in `fetchInfo()` skips to the catch section before returning.

When `shouldFail` is `false`, the `failableGetter()` doesn't fail and `fetchInfo()` returns the result.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43689806/7245977). Scope matters a bit here. Code inside the `do` block code after a throw will NOT be executed. However, code further down outside of the scope of the `do` block will be executed. I made a simple playground you can run to see for yourself.

```
import Foundation

let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 123, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "My error"])

func functionThatAlwaysThrows() throws {
    throw(error)
}

func myFunction() {
    do {
        try functionThatAlwaysThrows()

        // This will never print
        print("Continuing after throw inside do scope")
    } catch let err {
        print("Caught Error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // This will always print
    print("Continuing after throw outside do scope")
}
```

**Output:**

```
Caught Error: My error
Continuing after throw outside do scope
```

If you want more information on Error handling you can take a look at [the docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html)